# Why is console giving full jsFiddle link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little function which basically says to check if some text is exactly this or that:

```
function doSelect(text) {
  return $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
  });
}
```

The I run this in order to get the last string after `/wiki/` of some links like `<a href="/wiki/Geum_River" title="Geum River">Geum River</a>, <a href="/wiki/Korea" title="Korea">Korea</a>`

```
  let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
  doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').map(function(i, el) {
    return console.log(el.href.replace(pattern, ''));
  });
```

But when I check in console I get the whole jsFiddle link

```
https://fiddle.jshell.net/wiki/Geum_River
https://fiddle.jshell.net/wiki/Korea
```

I'd expect

```
Geum_River
Korea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the `href` attribute of the `<a>`. By doing this you retrieve the full absolute path of the URI, ie: `https://fiddle.jshell.net/wiki/Geum_River` instead of the relative path: `/wiki/Geum_River`

To change this behavior, use the attribute value directly, using `attr()`:

```
let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').map(function(i, el) {    
  var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
  console.log(result);
  return result;
});
```

Also double check that you're using `map()` correctly. It's intention is to create an array, but you're not doing anything with it's response. It would be worth using `each()` instead without the `return` if all you want to do is loop through the selected elements:

```
let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(i, el) {    
  var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: yes indeed! I need to simply loop them all, would you mind adding the loop in your answer? Thanks man

Comment: The logic is the same, just change `map` to `each` and remove the `return`. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
//let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(i, el) {    
  var name = $(this).attr('href').split('wiki/')[1].trim();
  console.log(result);
});
```